# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.entrySet()Ljava/util/Set

Tags: java, json, xml, org.json

I was supposed to convert to JSON string to XML. As suggested in one StackOverflow answer, I used the XML.toString method.

```
        String json_data = "{\"student\":{\"name\":\"Neeraj Mishra\", \"age\":\"22\"}}";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json_data);

    //converting json to xml
    String xml_data = XML.toString(obj);

    System.out.println(xml_data);
```

The above method is working perfectly fine for the latest version of org.json but my project uses 20080701 version of org.json and it is throwing the following error at this method XML.toString(obj);

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.json.JSONObject.entrySet()Ljava/util/Set;
at org.json.XML.toString(XML.java:502)
at org.json.XML.toString(XML.java:471)
at com.testing.main(testing.java:13)
```

And I cannot update the version.

Comment: But  you are not using `entrySet` in your code, please post full stack trace so we can see what causes the exception.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json.JSONObject.entrySet()Ljava/util/Set;
 at org.json.XML.toString(XML.java:502)
 at org.json.XML.toString(XML.java:471)
 at com.yodlee.aim.autoconfig.services.testing.main(testing.java:500) 
 
This is the stacktrace

Comment: Add that to the question instead by editing it and also point out what row this is in your code since we don't know the line numbers

Comment: updated @JoakimDanielson

Answer (score 1):

You can user the older version of org.json like "20160212"